# Dynamic Unicode Generation into the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, unicode

I have a function linking to a method for a JavaScript library I'm working on. Basically taking romanized Korean and converting it to specific Unicode sequences and re-inserting it into the DOM. The resulting strings that it generates are correct, but the re-insertion back into the DOM seems off...

For example: If I have the following in my DOM:

`<ko>hangug-eo</ko>`

The function is meant to convert it accordingly, replacing `hangug-eo` with `&#54620;&#44397;&#50612;` to show on the browser:

`한국어` within the `<ko>` tags...

The function that does the string setting within the DOM is as follows:

```
function (){
    var z=document.getElementsByTagName('ko');
    for(x=z.length;x--;){
        z[x].childNodes[0].data=kimchi.go(z[x].childNodes[0].data);
    }
}
```

However, it seems that all this seems to be doing is just placing the &# Unicode entities straight into the DOM without it converting to their respective character equivalents... So all I'm seeing is `&#54620;&#44397;&#50612;`

Can anyone please point out what I may be doing wrong?

`kimchi.go()` is the function that ultimately provides the Unicoded string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just set the text directly using `textContent` without having to use HTML entities:

```
z[x].textContent = '한국어';
```

But if you need to use HTML entities, just use innerHTML instead

```
z[x].innerHTML = kimchi.go(z[x].childNodes[0].data);
```

You can see the latter in the example below.

https://jsfiddle.net/nmL3to8w/1/

Comment: And in the case of the following message: `Detected UTF-16-encoded Basic Latin-only text without a byte order mark and without a transfer protocol-level declaration. Encoding this content in UTF-16 is inefficient and the character encoding should have been declared in any case.`, is there a way to prevent this from showing?

Comment: Which browser? I can't seem to recreate.

Comment: Firefox, console message under the JavaScript tab.

Comment: This is probably worthy of another question on SO but I'm thinking you just need this in your HTML `<head></head>` tag: `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: @Eliseo: Save your file as UTF-8, not UTF-16. (Do not use “Unicode” as an encoding when saving from Microsoft tools. This is MS's misleading name for UTF-16LE, which is not usually a suitable encoding for the web.) Note: if you don't have a unicode-safe environment you can also use JavaScript string literal escapes and say `'\uD55C\uAD6D\uC5B4'` to avoid having to fiddle with HTML.